# Django memcached library for python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, memcached

I'm trying to use memcached for my Django 1.8.5 (under python3) website.

At the moment I have tried pylibmc and python-memcached.

pylibmc gives me this error

```
libmemcached/get.cc:87 Assertion "ptr->query_id == query_id +1" failed for function "memcached_get_by_key" likely for "Programmer error, the query_id was not incremented."
Number of stack frames obtained: 24
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemcached.so.10 : memcached_get_by_key()+0x283
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemcached.so.10 : memcached_get()+0x1f
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pylibmc.cpython-34m.so : ()+0x61fd
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x3f6a
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalCodeEx()+0x15b
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x4490
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalCodeEx()+0x15b
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x4490
 /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python() [0x56a7ec]
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyObject_Call()+0x3a
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x1e2f
 /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python() [0x56a7ec]
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyObject_Call()+0x3a
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x1e2f
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x403d
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_EvalFrameEx()+0x403d
 /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python() [0x56a7ec]
 /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python() [0x4e21bd]
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyObject_Call()+0x3a
  /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python : PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords()+0x36
 /home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/bin/python() [0x5be452]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 : ()+0x8182
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : clone()+0x6d
```

Looks like a really rare thing, as looking on google I only found [pylibmc: 'Assertion "ptr->query_id == query_id +1" failed for function "memcached_get_by_key"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420007/pylibmc-assertion-ptr-query-id-query-id-1-failed-for-function-memcache)

Unfortunately I cant change how django handles the memcached lib..

Then I tried python-memcached

This time I got

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f00537e9f28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/media/francesco/A6528DA1528D76B9/Programmazione/Python/Spark/team_comp_site/teamcomp/apps.py", line 19, in ready
    client.get_stats()
  File "/home/francesco/virtualenvs/TeamCompSite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/memcache.py", line 338, in get_stats
    stats = line.split(' ', 2)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Looks like python-memcached only supports python2 (my bad for not checking before hand)

Let's try python3-memcached

The site loads!!!

Just to show me the familiar error page

```
Exception Value:    local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

Exception Location:     /home/xxxxx/virtualenvs/xxxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/memcache.py in _recv_value, line 1026
Python Executable:  /home/xxxxx/virtualenvs/xxxxx/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
```

So, what are the options for python3 (.4) memcached clients?

Answer (score 0):

The use of python3-memcached just trigger a cleaner string and byte buffer management.

In python2 unicode string were byte arrays and string were ascii or chain of `\uXXXX` chars. Conversion between ascii string to bytestring were silent but from bytestring to string explicite.

In python3 : unicode type does not exist anymore. You just have `str` and bare `bytearray`. Due to that everything must be explicit and so everything is more predictable. python-memcached library was so redevelopped to be adapted to this new --and simpler-- way to deal with strings in py3.